# How to identify a non-returner?

Tags: meditation-insight, academic-buddhism

Will they experience dukkha? Do they have thoughts which lead to form sankhara? What are the things they experience due to ignorance? Would they have mindfulness on five perceptions? Explain, when they experience a desire, how do they get rid of the desire? How is the desire different than from a sotapanna person?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it contains too many inaccurate (papanca) assumptions such as "thoughts which lead to form sankhara" and "mindfulness on five perceptions".

Comment: @DhammaDhatu The site's [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254) are unusually permissive. They're meant to allow question that may arise from misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Non-returner still has five fetters that can give rise to self-view and thus minor suffering, namely:

1. lust for form jhana
2. lust for formless spheres
3. conceit
4. restlessness (such as wondering what to do with 'their' life after realizing most are unteachable)
5. ignorance